# RMAN: not Connected to Database

Tags: oracle, rman

While issuing the `Restore Database` command, the RMAN utility says `Not Connected to ORACLE`, but When I try connecting Oracle using the command `Connect Target` it says `Already connected to ORACLE`.
All I want is to restore a Database from cold backup.

[image]

Comment: http://www.online-database.eu/recovery-manager-rman/83-clone-database-with-rman-on-another-host-option-3